# Como faço para exportar tabela no R em txt ou csv?

Tags: r, tabela-html, csv, exportação

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para exportar uma tabela de dados gerada dentro do R para formato `txt` ou `csv`?

Comment: Não quero ser chato, mas você podia dar uma olhada antes na documentação do R, além de ser extremamente simples a resposta é instantânea.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar a função `write.csv` ou `write.table` ([documentação](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)), como no exemplo abaixo.

```
nomes <- c("Scooby", "Salsicha", "Fred", "Velma", "Daphne")
idades <- c(10, 18, 20, 21, 19)
tabela <- data.frame(nome = nomes, idade = idades)
write.csv(tabela, "ScoobyDoo.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Lembrando que para ser automaticamente compatível com o Microsoft Office em português, você pode usar `write.csv2()`, que coloca automaticamente `sep=";"` e `dec=","`. De forma similar, `read.csv2()` pode ser usado para ler esses arquivos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Não tenho conhecimento de TI. Fico Agradeçido!